# Focus issue in Windows Eye screen reader

Tags: html, focus, screen-readers

I am displaying a div section 'errormessages' (Attributes `aria-live="rude" id="errormessages" tabindex="-1"`) in a page when any validation fails.

When tested with screen readers,

- JAWS 14: It reads the error messages displayed and the focus is set at the div section.
- Windows Eye 8.3: It reads the error messages displayed, but the focus is not being set to the div section.

Kindly can anyone suggest improvements?

```
$('#errormessages').show();
```

Comment: I'm not a Window Eyes user (I'm using JAWS), but what happens if you do: `$('#errormessages').show().focus()`?

Comment: That simply worked. Thank you !!!

Comment: StackOverflow experts, should I post this as an answer for future devs with such a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bring this div in focus regardless of the screen reader being used, explicitly set the focus to it:

```
$('#errormessages').show().focus();
```